# notificaciones push en Flutter con Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, fcm

Tengo una aplicación en Flutter que tendría notificaciones push  con Firebase Cloud Messaging, pero genera este error y no es posible recibir la notificación

[image: El codigo que aparece es este , al ejecutar la aplicación en un dispositivo móvil]

Anexo parte del código donde aparece la excepción, en el codigo se ha indicado la linea.

```
      _firebaseMessaging.configure(  //**Aqui aparece la excepcion**
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage: $message");
          String msg = 'notibody';
          String name = 'Chat SEZAMI';
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            msg = message['aps']['alert']['body'];
            name = message['aps']['alert']['title'];
          } else {
            msg = message['notification']['body'];
            name = message['notification']['title'];
          }

          String currentChat = (prefs.get('currentChat') ?? 'None');

          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            if (message['chatid'] != currentChat) {
              sendLocalNotification(name, msg);
            }
          } else {
            if (message['data']['chatid'] != currentChat) {
              sendLocalNotification(name, msg);
            }
          }

          ControlFirebase.instanace.getUnreadMSGCount();
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onLaunch: $message");
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onResume: $message");
        },
      );
```

Comment: lo primero, veo que tienes otra publicación sobre este error, te recomiendo que pulses [edit] y lo añadas ahí, lo segundo, este error dice *PluginRegistrantCallback is not set* o lo que es lo mismo, no tienes seteado ese callback. Sin el código que te causa la excepción es difícil saber que es exactamente, te recomiendo que lo añadas

Comment: ```  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage: $message");
          String msg = 'notibody';
          String name = 'Chat SEZAMI';
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            msg = message['aps']['alert']['body'];
            name = message['aps']['alert']['title'];
          } else {
            msg = message['notification']['body'];
            name = message['notification']['title'];
          }
  ControlFirebase.instanace.getUnreadMSGCount();
        },
 ```

Comment: @Nicolas Oñate la excepcion aparace en _firebaseMessagin.configure

Comment: @Nicolas Oñate, anexo parte del codigo donde aparece la excepcion   `    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print("onMessage: $message");
          String msg = 'notibody';
          String name = 'Chat SEZAMI';
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            msg = message['aps']['alert']['body'];
            name = message['aps']['alert']['title'];
          } else {
            msg = message['notification']['body'];
            name = message['notification']['title'];
          } `

Comment: ** _firebaseMessaging.configure**